# Раздать интернет по сети через один компьютер

Tags: сеть

Я новичок в этом деле, задание банальное для опытных сисадминов. Вообщем задача такая.Есть сеть, есть 3Г модем, есть роутер с портом под 3Г. Хочу пустить через свой компьютер интернет во всю сеть, чтобы следить за трафиком и контролировать всю активность пользователей.

Подскажите какое-либо ПО для контроля трафика, ну или просто посоветуйте, как лучше поступить. Сервера нет. Сеть без доменнов, простая.

Comment: Добавили бы еще используемую ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Сквид - как раз для админов, не для новичков :)

Плохо то, что для раздачи инета нужно будет почитать и поработать руками. Хорошо то, что этот опыт не будет лишним никогда.

Для раздачи инета через определенный компьютер используются программы под общим названием "прокси".

Попробуйте [3proxy](http://www.3proxy.ru/?l=RU).

Это чудо нужно поставить и чуточку поднастроить. По минимуму - вписать свой IP и IP провайдерских DNS. Также на других компьютерах нужно будет указать в настройках браузера подключение через прокси, и указать IP Вашего компьютера.

Очень хорошо [здесь](http://bozza.ru/art-94.html) пишут о настройке.

Сам пользовался одно время этим прокси. Соседу сбрасывал эти же ссылки, человек далекий от компьютеров все смог сделать сам :)

Для раздачи также можно воспользоваться функцией "Разрешить другим пользователям использовать подключение к Интернету данного компьютера". Эта фишка находится на вкладке "Доступ" свойства подключения к сети. Там все подробно описано, но я таким способом ни разу не воспользовался, рассказать мне об этом нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Как на unix - пока не знаю. На маздае - две сетевухи. Настроите ип-ы по вкусу (1 для связи с модемом (одна подсеть) и 1 для связи с др.компами (2-я подсеть)). Потом ищете в реестре значение "ipenableroute" , ставите двоичное "1". в настройках сетевых девайсов (ип которые) - гейтом ставите ип другой карты. Примерно так.

```
девайс1: (к модему)ип 192.168.1.2маск 255.255.255.0гейт 192.168.0.2девайс2: (к подсети с компами)ип 192.168.0.2маск 255.255.255.0гейт 192.168.1.2
```

Как-то так. Ребутитесь. Теперь пинг должен ходить с 192.168.0.1-254 до 192.168.1.1-254. Итак. Чего мы добились? Теперь у нас есть связь между модемом и сетью. Причем, ВЕСЬ траффик проходит через вашу машину. (Палево только  том, что TTL теперь на 1 меньше) с программами разбирайтесь сами, по ним ничего не знаю.

P.S. через реестр в Маздае можно назначать одному интерфейсу сразу 2(и больше XD) ипа. Можно попытаться через 1 карту все это сделать. Я пробовал извращаться, но тогда, кажется, ничего не получилось.

Фуф! Надеюсь, у вас Маздай, а то зря писал столько. )))) Удачи!

Comment: один вопрос.. что такое "Маздай"  ? о.0

Comment: windows must die |_маст дай_| _маздай_

Comment: Блин, ошибочка с масками. На обоих картах она 255.255.0.0

Comment: нет, не получилось. всё настроил по инструкции, скачал нужный софт, но ИП со шлэзами настроить так и не удалось. всё просто, всё понятно, но не работеает.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен прокси сервер, какой - дело вкуса. Рекомендую squid. )

Comment: А как насчёт UserGate ? Там и сервер подключения можно указать, и статистика ведётся и прокси можно настроить... в принципе удобная вещь...Но ещё вопрос - спрашивал у людей, мне говорили что это не осуществить без 2-ой сетевой карты. Одной обойтись никак не получится ?

Comment: Можно подключить к сети вашу машину и остальные машины через роутер,на роутере разрешить доступ в инет только одной машине-вашей,поднять на ней прокси и остальные компы пускать в инет через прокси то бишь ваш комп.Две сетевухи как правило нужны для маршрутизатора,коим в описанной мной схеме будет ваш роутер 3г

Comment: А Прокси умеет контролировать не HTTP, FTP, Gopher трафик? Все остальное останется за кадром.

Comment: Всё зависит от настроек прокси-сервера,проблем возникнуть не должно)

Answer (score 0):

UserGate - пользовалься - осталься очень доволен,

Answer (score 0):

я использовал httpd для линукс. Настроил в качестве прокси и все работает. Раздает на другой комп через wi-fi